# Passenger standalone rise nginx error on --ssl

Tags: nginx, passenger

I trying to start passenger with SSL on mac os localhost but get this:

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "ssl_certificate" directive in (way to config)
```

everything worked well just before I reinstall mac os from a backup image. All looking same as long as I can see.
Any ideas where to look?

Answer (score 1):

Passenger author here. This probably means you didn't specify --ssl-certificate and --ssl-certificate-key as well. Which Passenger version are you using, what is your exact invocation?

Comment: Standalone 5.0.10

passenger start --ssl --ssl-certificate ./ssl/server.crt --ssl-certificate-key ./ssl/server.key

Comment: Can you set the environment variable `PASSENGER_DEBUG=1`, then run `passenger start` as you did before, and tell me what you see on screen?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7nf8DBq1lg3cmtZYVZ4Vlp1MlE/view?usp=sharing

and this one with --ssl


https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7nf8DBq1lg3dXRfT1Jud3loQUU/view?usp=sharing

Lines in nginx config is 
            ssl_certificate /Users/pavelegorkin/pathtoproject/ssl/server.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key /Users/pavelegorkin/pathtoproject/ssl/server.key;

Comment: What I meant is, you should run this: `env PASSENGER_DEBUG=1 passenger start --ssl --ssl-certificate ./ssl/server.crt --ssl-certificate-key ./ssl/server.key`. What do you see?